# Google Calendar Event timings in edit mode automatically add or subtract hours

Tags: android, events, google-calendar-api

I did the following code to create the event in the Google calendar programtically:

```
Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
            ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
            event.put("calendar_id", 1);
            event.put("title", generate_title);
            event.put("description", "Swim Lesson in " + ScheduleLessonFragement5.Calendar_Event.get(i).get("sitename"));
            event.put("eventLocation", ScheduleLessonFragement5.Calendar_Event.get(i).get("sitename"));
            event.put("dtstart", startMillis);
            event.put("dtend", endMillis);
            event.put("allDay", 0);   // 0 for false, 1 for true
            event.put("eventStatus", 1);
            event.put("hasAlarm", 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true
            event.put("eventTimezone", TimeZone.getDefault().toString());


            try {
                Uri eventUri = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);
                eventids.add (eventUri.getLastPathSegment());
                ContentValues reminders = new ContentValues();
                reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventUri.getLastPathSegment());
                reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
                reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 30);

                Uri uri2 = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, reminders);
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(""+eventids);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events/" + String.valueOf(eventids.get(0))));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        Utility.ping(this, "Events added successfully in Calendar.");`
```

The above code does create events and also open the first event with the inserted timings for display in view mode but when i press the edit mode its subtract exactly 5:30 hours from the given timings.
Whereas for my client it adds exactly 7 hours to the hours given by him from the app. Example images have been given below....I searched a lot and it says that the issue is regarding the Timezones...i didnt get it..
[When open calendar event in view mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZJw0.jpg)
[When open calendar event in edit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDCC5.jpg)

Also i went throught the following link but no success:

[enter link description here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9536/how-can-i-fix-this-time-zone-problem-with-calendar-events-that-started-after-ins)

Comment: When you save the event, what happens to the time, does it go back to normal?

Comment: When we open the event in edit mode and change the time than it changes the original time by adding or subtracting the timezone values...

Comment: But when you save it, what happens?

Comment: when we save it it does not go to normal